# Find shortest set of paths connecting all nodes

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have a set of points in 2D coordinate space.

I would like to find the set of paths that connect them all with the shortest total length. (heuristic solution ok, doesn't need to be exact.)

This might sound like the traveling salesman problem, but it's different. I am not looking for a cycle that will visit each point once and only once. I just need each point connected to at least one other point such that all points in the set are at least indirectly connected to each other with the sum of the lengths of the chosen connections to be minimized. It should therefore be acyclic to minimize the sum of the lengths of the connections.

A simple nearest neighbor algorithm (i.e., connect each point to its nearest neighbor that's not already connected to it) doesn't work because small clusters that are far away from each other will end up isolated, and you'll always end up creating cycles.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the MST problem.

Comment: ah yes that sounds like it.

Comment: Maybe also related: the Steiner tree problem

Comment: How many points?

Answer (score 1):

Like the others pointed out, you need to buid a MST. But if you want to choose from all pair of points (potential edges for the MST), you end of with a huge amount of edges to process which blows up runtime and memory.

It would propably be faster to start with any point, connect it to its closest neighbour that does NOT create a cycle and repeat this step until everything is connected.

This is another more uncommon way to build a minimum spanning tree which should be faster in your application.

If you want, I can (try to) prove the algorithm I just proposed.

In case you arrive at different solutions for your problem, notice that a MST is not necessarily unique, there may be multiple optimal solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m understanding your question correctly, what you’re looking for is a minimum spanning tree (often abbreviated as MST). An MST is just a subset of paths that

- (a) connects all points,
- (b) has the lowest total length possible while doing that, and
- (c) has no cycles.

There are several well-known algorithms that can find an MST, such as Prim’s Algorithm and Kruskal’s Algorithm — I’ll walk you through Kruskal’s, which I personally find to be most intuitive. If you’re interested, you should be able to find additional algorithms online or in algorithms textbooks.

---

Kruskal’s begins by sorting the individual paths by length. Using that list, we’re then able to create an MST by repeating the following process until all points/vertices are included in our tree:

1. Consider the shortest path in the list.

   - If it would create a cycle in your MST, don’t add it to the tree (just remove it from the list).
   - Otherwise, add it to the tree (and remove it from the list).

Eventually, you will end up with a tree that

- (a) connects all points — guaranteed since each path is considered, each vertex eligible to be in the MST must be on a path, and adding a path to reach a previously unconnected vertex cannot create a cycle;
- (b) has the lowest total length possible — guaranteed because paths are added in the order of ascending length; and
- (c) has no cycles — guaranteed because the algorithm explicitly avoids this.

---

Notes:

(1) When dealing with MST (and other graph problems), we often call parts by specific names: the set of points is a “graph”, a specific point or node is a “vertex”, paths between vertices are “edges”, and lengths of edges are “weights”.

(2) Kruskal’s Algorithm runs in O(ElogV) time, where E is the number of paths/edges, and V is the number of points/vertices.

(3) If your graph has any vertices or sets of vertices that are disconnected from the rest of the data set, you’ll end up with multiple MSTs in an “MST forest”.

(4) A graph can have more than one MST; for example in [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTYO.png), the minimum length of the MST is 6 — which is achieved by both of the following MSTs: [MST1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6kb2.png), [MST2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9hdS.png)

(5) Determining if adding a path would create a cycle can actually be tricky; one method of doing this uses the UnionFind data structure, which you can play around with [here](https://visualgo.net/en/ufds).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing sounds like Kruskal's algorithm:

> Kruskal's algorithm is a minimum-spanning-tree algorithm which finds
>   an edge of the least possible weight that connects any two trees in
>   the forest.It is a greedy algorithm in graph theory as it finds a
>   minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted graph adding increasing
>   cost arcs at each step. This means it finds a subset of the edges
>   that forms a tree that includes every vertex, where the total weight
>   of all the edges in the tree is minimized. If the graph is not
>   connected, then it finds a minimum spanning forest (a minimum spanning
>   tree for each connected component).

[image]

Kruskal time complexity worst case is O(E log E),this because we need to sort the edges. Prim time complexity worst case is O(E log V) with priority queue or even better, O(E+V log V) with Fibonacci Heap. You should use Kruskal when the graph is sparse, i.e.small number of edges,like E=O(V), when the edges are already sorted or if we can sort them in linear time. We should use Prim when the graph is dense, i.e number of edges is high ,like E=O(V²)